# Are S(g) and U(g) isomorphic as g-modules for g Lie algebra over F_p ? Are S(g)^g and U(g)^g isomorphic as com.algs ? 

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

If $g$ is Lie algebra over field char(k)=0,
then the following facts are well-known:

1) S(g) and U(g) are isomorphic as $g$-modules. (Symmetrization map S(g)->U(g) gives isomorphism).

2) S(g)^g and ZU(g)=U(g)^g are isomorphic as commutative algebras. (The [Duflo map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duflo_isomorphism)
defines is isomorphism which is combination of symmetrization map with some intricate corrections by terms of smaller degree).

Both facts are based on the symmetrization.
If we consider $g$ over field char(k)$\ne$0, there is NO symmetrization map.
So I wonder the following:

**Question** are the facts above true for Lie algebras over char(k)$\ne$0 ?

---

Notations

U(g) - [universal enveloping algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) (non-commutative associative algebra defined by relations $[x_i, x_j] = \sum_k c_{ij}^k x_k$, for any linear bases $x_k$ of $g$.

S(g) - symmetric algebra of $g$ (defined as $k[x_1...x_n]$ for any bases $x_k$ of $g$.

S(g)^g, U(g)^g means subspaces of g-invariants (g act by zero).

Symmetrization map is defined as $S(x_1..x_k) = 1/k! \sum_{\sigma}  \prod_l {x_{\sigma(l)} $.

Duflo map is not so easy to write so let me just mention some MO questions:

[Is the Duflo map for Lie algs. unique ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80025/is-the-duflo-map-for-lie-algs-unique)

[Capelli determinant = Duflo ( determinant)  - was it known ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92348/capelli-determinant-duflo-determinant-was-it-known)

---

Remark

For the case of gl_n there are so-called [Capelli generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capelli's_identity) of the center of U(g),
which can be defined over any char. So I think that the center of U(gl) is the same as 
for char(k)=0 the result is true. (It is NOT the same as in char=0, as I mistakenly wrote first, since there should be generators corresponding to a^p (which are S(g)^g for any a)).

I think the same is true for other classical semi-simples - there are analogous Capelli like formulas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Question 2 has a negative answer. Indeed, let $L =sl(2,k)$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>3$ and let {$e,h,f$} be the standard basis of $L$. Then it is well-known (and was first proved by Rudakov-Shafarevich in the late 60s) that the centre $Z(L)$ of $U(L)$ is generated by $E=e^p$, $F=f^p$, $H=h^p-h$ and a Casimir element $C$ subject to the relation
$$4EF+H^2=\prod_{i\in{\mathbb F}_p}(C-i^2)=C^p-2C^{(p+1)/2}+C.$$ Furthermore, the maximal spectrum of $Z(L)$ is a hypersurface in ${\mathbb A}^4$ given by the above equation.  On the other hand, it follows from a result of Brown-Goodearl that the Azumaya locus of $U(L)$ coincides with the smooth locus of ${\rm Specm\ }Z(L)$. So the modular representation theory of $sl(2,k)$ yields that ${\rm Specm\ }Z(L)$
has exactly $(p-1)/2$ singular points (one can also see this directly by differentiating the above equation).

On the other hand, it is also known (and not difficult to see directly) that $S(L)^L$ is generated by
$X=e^p$, $Y=f^p$, $Z=h^p$ and $\Omega=4ef+h^2$ subject to the relation $4XY+Z^2=\Omega^p$. Moreover, ${\rm Specm\ }S(L)^L$ is a hypersurface in ${\mathbb A}^4$ given by the above equation. This hypersurface has a unique singular point at the origin.
Since $(p-1)/2>1$ under our assumptions on $p$, we see that the $k$-algebras $Z(L)$ and $S(L)^L$ cannot be isomorphic.

As far as I know the answer to Question 1 is unknown, in general, although there do exist finite dimensional Lie algebras $L$ for which $L\subset U_1(L)$ is NOT a direct summand of $U(L)$ (if $U(L)$ is isomorphic to $S(L)$ as $ad(L)$-modules, then $U(L)$ must contain an isomorphic copy of $L$ as a direct summand, but that copy doesn't have to lie in the first component $U_1(L)$ of the canonical filtration of $U(L)$).

If we require the stronger condition that an isomrphism $S(L)\rightarrow U(L)$ sends $S^1(L)$ onto $L\subset U_1(L)$ (which is obviously true for the symmetrisation map), then the answer to Question 1 is NO. For that condition to hold the Lie algebra $L$ must admit at least one $[p]$-th power map, i.e. must be ${\it restrictable}$ (this observation is due to Michel Duflo). The majority of finite dimensional simple Lie algebras are non-restrictable, and the smallest example is the $3$-dimensional simple Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: @Alexander Premet Thank you very much ! 

Comment: @Alexander Premet are there relations like formula 1 known for sl_n/ gl_n, not just sl_2 ? I mean in gl_n we have n-Casimirs e.g. Tr(E^k), k=1...n. So we may expect that e_{ij}^p are related to powers of these elements ? May be some nice formulas can be obtained ? 

Comment: There are similar relations for $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ (any $p$ and any $n$) and for $\frak{sl}_n$ with $p\not|n$. Sadly, almost nothing is know about the symmetric invariants of $\mathfrak{sl}_{kp}$. Of course, when $p<n$ the invariants $Tr(E^k)$ will fail to generate 
$S(\mathfrak{gl}_n)^{GL_n}$ (this is because in characteristic $p$ we have that $Tr(E^p)=(Tr(E))^p$). But these can be replaced by the basic invarints arising as the coefficients of the characteristic poynomial of a generic matrix. More on this can be found in my joint paper with Rudolf Tange; see J. Algebra 294 (2005) 177–195.

Answer (score 6):

Your question may be related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89795/symmetrization-for-hyperalgebras-in-positive-characteristic/89826#89826) about hyperalgebras. In my answer there, I gave a reference to a paper of Friedlander and Parshall (*Rational actions associated with the adjoint representation*, Ann. scient. Ec. Norm. Sup., 4e serie, t. 20, 1987, p. 215 a 226), which shows that the answer to your question (1) is yes if $g$ is the Lie algebra of a simple algebraic group.

For a simple algebraic group $G$ and Lie algebra $g = Lie(G)$, I think that looking at the spaces of $g$-invariants in $S(g)$ and $U(g)$ are probably the same as the spaces of $G_1$-invariants, where $G_1$ is the first Frobenius kernel of $G$. Then the results in Section 4 of the Friedlander-Parshall paper may be relevant to your question (2).

Comment: @Christopher Thank you very much for yours answers and links ! I will look at the paper you suggest. 

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in some particular cases it is known, see e.g. [this recent result](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dimagur/OzAbstract.pdf).

I was looking at that a while ago, and at least it became clear to me that one has to be very careful with lifting the $p$th powers from the Poisson centre of $S(\mathfrak{g})$ (which is where symmetrisation fails most dramatically), e.g. for $\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{F}_3\{x,y\}$ with $[x,y]=y$ the Poisson central elements $x^3$ and $y^3$ lift to central elements $x^3-x$ and $y^3$ respectively.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you !!! By the way concerning center of U(n) and U(b) in char =0  there are recent papers by Kostant:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4494 Center of U(n), Cascade of Orthogonal Roots, and a Construction of Lipsman-Wolf http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2362 Coadjoint structure of Borel subgroups and their nilradicals the paper you mentioned discussed more complicated case char=p, while Kostant char =0. 

Comment: By the way for [x,y]=x are there positive answers ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if it is known, and if yes if it is written somewhere. I think I did convince myself in positive answer for this case, but it was mere curiousity so I did not dig too deep.

Answer (score 1):

A sort of involved and (seemingly very partial) variant of Duflo isomorphism in characretristic $p$ is claimed in the following paper: N.A. Koreshkov, Central elements and invariants in modular Lie algebras, Russ. Math. (Izv. VUZ) 46 (2002), N7, 20-24 (Russian original is available, for example, at http://www.ksu.ru/journals/izv_vuz/arch/2002/07/05-7.PDF ). Roughly, it is proved there that for a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a finite field $\mathbb Z_p$, a certain modification of $S(\overline{L})^{\overline L}$ is isomorphic to a certain subring of $U(\overline L)^{\overline L}$, where $\overline L$ is obtained from $L$ by some (infinite) field extension.